# How to extract the rows containing two matching values from another excel table?

Tags: excel

I have an excel table with 11 columns like :

```
0   HS00894 PFKP    6PFRUCTPHOS-RXN 2.7.1.11    Homo sapiens    EV-EXP  Homo sapiens    6-phosphofructokinase   https://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bfind_sub?mode=bfind&max_hit=1000&dbkey=Homo+sapiens&keywords=6-phosphofructokinase   ANAEROFRUCAT-PWY
1   HS08399 HK2 GLUCOKIN-RXN    2.7.1.1/2.7.1.2 Homo sapiens    EV-EXP  Homo sapiens    alpha-D-glucopyranose 6-kinase  https://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bfind_sub?mode=bfind&max_hit=1000&dbkey=Homo+sapiens&keywords=alpha-D-glucopyranose 6-kinase  ANAEROFRUCAT-PWY
2   HS08548 HK3 GLUCOKIN-RXN    2.7.1.1/2.7.1.2 Homo sapiens    EV-EXP  Homo sapiens    alpha-D-glucopyranose 6-kinase  https://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bfind_sub?mode=bfind&max_hit=1000&dbkey=Homo+sapiens&keywords=alpha-D-glucopyranose 6-kinase  ANAEROFRUCAT-PWY
3   HS08136 HK1 GLUCOKIN-RXN    2.7.1.1/2.7.1.2 Homo sapiens    EV-EXP  Homo sapiens    alpha-D-glucopyranose 6-kinase  https://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bfind_sub?mode=bfind&max_hit=1000&dbkey=Homo+sapiens&keywords=alpha-D-glucopyranose 6-kinase  ANAEROFRUCAT-PWY
4   HS02935 GCK GLUCOKIN-RXN    2.7.1.1/2.7.1.2 Homo sapiens    EV-EXP  Homo sapiens    glucokinase https://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bfind_sub?mode=bfind&max_hit=1000&dbkey=Homo+sapiens&keywords=glucokinase ANAEROFRUCAT-PWY
5   HS02693 GPI PGLUCISOM-RXN   5.3.1.9 Homo sapiens    No Evidence Code    Homo sapiens    Glucose-6-phosphate isomerase   https://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bfind_sub?mode=bfind&max_hit=1000&dbkey=Homo+sapiens&keywords=Glucose-6-phosphate isomerase   ANAEROFRUCAT-PWY
6   G-9935  pgi PGLUCISOM-RXN   5.3.1.9 Lactococcus lactis  EV-EXP  Lactococcus lactis  glucose-6-phosphate isomerase   https://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bfind_sub?mode=bfind&max_hit=1000&dbkey=Lactococcus+lactis&keywords=glucose-6-phosphate isomerase ANAEROFRUCAT-PWY
7   HS07832 PFKM    6PFRUCTPHOS-RXN 2.7.1.11    Homo sapiens    EV-EXP  Homo sapiens    6-phosphofructokinase   https://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bfind_sub?mode=bfind&max_hit=1000&dbkey=Homo+sapiens&keywords=6-phosphofructokinase   ANAEROFRUCAT-PWY
8   HS06881 PFKL    6PFRUCTPHOS-RXN 2.7.1.11    Homo sapiens    EV-EXP  Homo sapiens    6-phosphofructokinase   https://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bfind_sub?mode=bfind&max_hit=1000&dbkey=Homo+sapiens&keywords=6-phosphofructokinase   ANAEROFRUCAT-PWY
9   G-9934  pfkA    6PFRUCTPHOS-RXN 2.7.1.11    Lactococcus lactis  EV-EXP  Lactococcus lactis  6-phosphofructokinase   https://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bfind_sub?mode=bfind&max_hit=1000&dbkey=Lactococcus+lactis&keywords=6-phosphofructokinase ANAEROFRUCAT-PWY
10  HS06234 ALDOB   F16ALDOLASE-RXN 4.1.2.13    Homo sapiens    EV-EXP  Homo sapiens    fructose-bisphosphate aldolase  https://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bfind_sub?mode=bfind&max_hit=1000&dbkey=Homo+sapiens&keywords=fructose-bisphosphate aldolase  ANAEROFRUCAT-PWY
```

I have another table like:

```
Lactococcus lactis  glucose-6-phosphate isomerase
Homo sapiens    6-phosphofructokinase
Homo sapiens    6-phosphofructokinase
Lactococcus lactis  6-phosphofructokinase
Homo sapiens    fructose-bisphosphate aldolase
Homo sapiens    fructose-bisphosphate aldolase
Homo sapiens    fructose-bisphosphate aldolase
Enterococcus faecalis   fructose bisphosphate aldolase
Homo sapiens    triosephosphate isomerase
Lactococcus lactis  triosephosphate isomerase
Lactobacillus delbrueckii   triosephosphate isomerase
Homo sapiens    glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate dehydrogenase
```

Now, I want to take each row from the second table and search for that combination present within the first table and extract the respective row. I have many thousand rows, so manually it is impossible. How can I perform that in Excel?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your tables have `space` between the fields.  Since the data also contains `space` within the field, it is almost impossible to paste your data properly into a worksheet. Suggest you redo your presentation using a field separator that is **NOT** contained within the field (eg `tab`, `pipe`, etc) to make it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to understand exactly what you are after, but assuming that each entry in your 'find' list is unique, and there is only one match in your 'search' list, this vba would do the job. If there are multiple matches in your 'search' list, then remove the 'Exit For' line.

```
Sub SearchData()

Dim SearchRange As Range: Set SearchRange = Range("A1:L11") 'set this range to the data you want to search
Dim SearchRange_Attribute1_Column As Integer: SearchRange_Attribute1_Column = 4 'set this number to the column of the first attribute
Dim SearchRange_Attribute2_Column As Integer: SearchRange_Attribute2_Column = 2 'set this number to the column of the second attribute

Dim FindRange As Range: Set FindRange = Range("A15:B25")
Dim sht As Worksheet: Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add()
Dim shtRow As Integer: shtRow = 1

Dim FoundMatch As Boolean: FoundMatch = False

For Each findRow In FindRange.Rows
    For Each searchRow In SearchRange.Rows
        If findRow.Cells(1).Text = searchRow.Cells(SearchRange_Attribute1_Column).Text Then
            If findRow.Cells(2).Text = searchRow.Cells(SearchRange_Attribute2_Column).Text Then
                searchRow.Copy
                sht.Activate
                sht.Range("A" & shtRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                shtRow = shtRow + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, CJ K. Unfortunately, it is not retrieving any row at all.

Comment: @deep771992, The assumption here is that you have enough understanding of vba to map the ranges in the script to the correct ranges in your spreadsheet. (See comments in script). This is also case-sensitive. if you want a case-agnostic search, you will need to run the cell text throu Lcase() for example...